# Using the latest version of a GitHub Action

Tags: github, github-actions

Is it possible to use the latest version of a published GitHub Action from the Marketplace in a workflow?

This would be nice if it was somehow possible:

```
      - name: "TODO to Issue"
        uses: "alstr/todo-to-issue-action@latest"
```

For example, with a `npm` package you can do `npm install node@latest` to use the latest version of that package.

On an action's page, when you click on "Use latest version", it shows the following dialogue, where the version number is hard-coded:

[image: example action]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax is `{owner}/{repo}@{ref}` so you can point to the `master` branch as follow:

```
      - name: "TODO to Issue"
        uses: "alstr/todo-to-issue-action@master"
```

BTW In case of a major update, any breaking changes could stop your workflow, so I would suggest to tag to a major version, for example `@4`:

```
      - name: "TODO to Issue"
        uses: "alstr/todo-to-issue-action@v4"
```

Comment: This is certainly easier, but it's intriguing why GH doesn't seem to have a way to use `@latest`

Comment: @jv-k se my update

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to choose `@tag` or `@master`. If you select `@tag`, you will not be able to use the new features and bug fixes for that actions. If you select `@master`, you will worry about the latest code not being compatible with your earlier logic.

I'm an actions author, and created a major version tag `v1`. When new code is released, the new tag `v1.0.x` is created and I updated tag `v1` with the new commit sha. In the Marketplace README.md, users are reminded to use `@v1` to use compatible new features in a timely manner, and to use `@v1.0.x` to seek stability.

In fact, some well-known actions such as [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout/tags) do just that. You see, the latest commit sha of tag v4 is always the same as the latest v4.x.x.